# PHP class - error in linux but works in windows

Tags: php, class, web

I've created a class and defined its namespace and am calling it in the index using `use` followed by its namespace,besides, i've created autoloader file. it runs on windows all goes smoothly, but if in linux I get an error message

> Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Class' lib \ MVC \ Router 'not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pos-hm-git/index.php:6 Trace trail: # 0 {main} thrown into /opt/lampp/htdocs/pos-hm-git/index.php on line 6

[Structure Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OCJd.png)

**index.php**

```html
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoloader.php';

use lib\MVC\Router;

$kernel = new  Router($_GET);
$controller = $kernel->getController();
$controller->executeAction();
 ?>
```

**autoloader.php**

```html
<?php

spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();
?>
```

**Router.php**

```html
<?php
namespace lib\MVC;

class Router
{
  private $controller;
  private $action;
  private $urlparams;
  private $controller_namespace = "\\Controllers\\";
  private $base_controller_name = "lib\\MVC\\BaseController";

  function __construct($url)
  {
    //memasukan semua parameter dari index yang di tangkap dengan GET
    $this->urlparams = $url;
    //menentukan nama controller
    if (empty($this->urlparams['controller'])) {
        $this->controller = $this->controller_namespace . "Home";
    }else {
        $this->controller = $this->controller_namespace . $this->urlparams['controller'];
    }

    //menentukan aksi yang akan dijalankan
    if (empty($this->urlparams['action'])) {
        $this->action = "index";
    }else {
        $this->action = $this->urlparams['action'];
    }
  }

  public function getController()
  {
    if (class_exists($this->controller)) {
        $parent = class_parents($this->controller);

        if (in_array($this->base_controller_name, $parent)) {
          if (method_exists($this->controller, $this->action)) {

            return new $this->controller($this->action, $this->urlparams);

          }else {
            throw new \Exception("Aksi tidak ditemukan, braaaaay", 1);
          }
        }else {
          throw new \Exception("class untuk controller salah braaay, coba sekali lagi", 1);
        }
    }else {
      throw new \Exception("Controller tidak ditemukan, braaay", 1);
    }
  }

}


?>
```

Comment: Looks like you are defaulting to spl_autoload.  Which I think uses your include path.   If you edit: your question to include code (rather than your linked images), please add output of `get_include_path()`;

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php, in the comments (#15 daniel), it suggests this function lower cases class names for file name mappings by default.  Which would break on *nix.  Perhaps try a PSR-4 compatible autoloader, or write your own function.

Comment: ok, i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

I bet on the filename. For Linux it's two different files - MVC.php and mvc.php. For Windows it's the same - so it works.

Comment: thanks a lot, brother. but i am pretty sure that the lettering is well. please see the pictures if you don't mind.